# Deleting an AWS cloud formation stack does not delete associated resource's mappings - a lambda function event-source mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to delete an aws cloud formation stack and its associated resources. But, it seems deleting the CF stack deletes the stack and associated lambda function, but does not delete the lambda function's event-source mappings to SQS. I use the following command to delete the stack:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name "${g_stackName}" --region "${aws_region}"
```

Comment: Did you create the event-source mappings as part of the cloud formation template itself or did run the template and then manually add the mappings yourself later?

Comment: Got you. I created them later through AWS CLI commands and not withing the stack creation command!

Comment: As @ilooner mentioned, the trick was to create all the resources while creating the CF stack. Further, I had to add the 'DependsOn' on each resource, which depended on the lambda function to be created before they got set!. Thanks @ilooner!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across still looking for a solution - you can delete the problematic event source using [`aws-cli`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) and the [`delete-event-source-mapping` command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/delete-event-source-mapping.html)

E.g.: when trying to re-create the stack, in your error message about the Event Source already existing you'll have the UUID of that event source (e.g.: a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-11111EXAMPLE) - take note of it as you'll need to use it.

Then on your cli:

1. Make sure you have fresh auth token for the account you're editing (you probably already [configured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/welcome-examples.html) your env for this)
2. Now you should be able to start the deletion :

```
aws lambda delete-event-source-mapping --uuid a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-11111EXAMPLE
```

your output should look something like this:

```
{
    "UUID": "a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-11111EXAMPLE",
    "StateTransitionReason": "USER_INITIATED",
    "LastModified": 1569285870.271,
    "BatchSize": 5,
    "State": "Deleting",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function",
    "EventSourceArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:123456789012:mySQSqueue"
}
```